# Can't download image with request library

Tags: node.js, http, https, request, download

I'm trying to download an image the way it's described in the [readme](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/README.md#streaming). Here is my code:

`request("https://www.google.com/images/google_favicon_128.png").pipe(fs.createWriteStream('google_favicon_128.png'))`

The problem is that the file is always 0 bytes. If I download with the standard `https` library and handle the `data` and `end` events it works just fine. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error or warning ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested a basic example using node v0.10.15 and the latest version of request (2.25.0):

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

request("https://www.google.com/images/google_favicon_128.png").pipe(fs.createWriteStream('google_favicon_128.png'));
```

It saved the file just fine.  Could it be a permissions issue in the directory you are writing the file to?

What version of node & request are you using?